# supportsAllDrives is appearing as deprecated what was is the alternative to this parameter?

Tags: google-api

supportsAllDrives   boolean 
Warning: This item is deprecated.
Deprecated - Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. This parameter will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards all applications are assumed to support shared drives. (Default: false)

supportsTeamDrives  boolean 
Warning: This item is deprecated.
Deprecated use supportsAllDrives instead. (Default: false)

both got deprecated but what is the alternative to both parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

> in 2020 GDrive will start ignoring those parameters and will always
>   list contents from Team drives, too, so effectively setting them to
>   false in KGAPI would look like a bug.

From https://phabricator.kde.org/D20789

Not really clear from the documentation if we need to update anything.
Looks like setting the parameter `supportsAllDrives` to `true` resolve the issue and will be ignored in the future because it will list the shared drives by default.

Comment: It seems like it's not quite ignored just yet (Dec 2022).  I had an issue where I needed to add it to the URL when doing a resumable upload, otherwise it errored out with the parent ID of a folder in a shared drive.  Worked fine directly to the root of the shared drive, just not any folders.